# How to Restore completely deleted Virtualbox Linux.VDI on Linux ? Already restored it but to DD image, don't have a backup

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mount, virtualbox, dd

so I accidentally deleted the Linux.VDI from my Virtualbox it's a Linux/Ubuntu64 VDI,

I had a success by restoring the file but only to a Linux.dd , I have tried different things to get it back working on my VBox but without any success

Yes I did convert too the dd back to vdi file and tried to add it to Virtualbox but it always shows Error, the Error is usaully i can't add the VDI to Vbox instance or when i boot it up it shows No bootable medium found...

Does anyone know how to correctly do it on Linux, can i run the dd file in Virtualbox or how to correctly do it if i converted the dd back to vdi ?

By the way the host is linux and vbox vdi is also linux

I want a way to access the files on this VDI or DD image , how can I do it ?

Maybe there is a way to access Files that was on this Disk Image, maybe I don't even have to convert dd back to vbox image and I can simply do it by using some programming tech

Comment: You have to explain how you did the recover with precise steps and commands done to do this. And also what is the meaning of dd in this context. The only thing I can imagine to recover this would have been to have the VM running when the file was deleted, hopefully meaning an Unix/Linux (no idea about Windows) hypervisor file descriptor was still attached to the "deleted" file and the whole VM disk could be copied more or less easily as long as the VM was running. Anything else allowing 100% safe recovery looks like heuristics.